# Text on Path Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path

I wanted to put the text inside the triangle path. I tried but the text is not guite readable. I want something like on picture I provided.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The example you give is not an instance of text on a path, but rather regular point text being skewed.

1. type your text, for example, 'EXHIB' in your example
2. select it with the black arrow tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) if it isn't already
3. choose the Shear tool, possibly 'hidden' under the Scale tool (<kbd>S</kbd>)
4. click and drag into the desired shape *or* double-click the shear tool to enter a degree value
5. repeat with 'ITION' with the inverse angle.